# Asynchronous MySQL Queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: database, asynchronous, stored-procedures, hook, codeigniter-3

I have to call a procedure from a controller which does some calculations.

thing is i don't care about its result set. I wanted it to be async.

Look at below my code:

**Controller.php**

```
do something....

call procedure($params);

process something else

return $array('type' => 'success);
```

I want procedure call to be async. i looked for a solution in hooks. seems like i can't call a specific function from a controller. i believe hooks are not async even though we get solution.

got this [Library](https://github.com/fideloper/CI-Hook) but this is pretty old and not async.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: i went through observer design pattern and i am trying to implement it.

Answer (score -2):

I think it isn't possible because php is synchronous. In PHP you can make call to program writing in async language (javascript for example) which runs the query and after puts all results into a file. Next in php you can wait for file exists and if not do something else. That program can be a http server which only take request. But I think if you really need something that you shoud write it in another language.